# ToList<T>() vs ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, generics

Does it make sense to specify a concrete type in `ToList<T>()`, `AsEnumerable<T>()`, etc methods?

Will `.ToList<SomeClass>()` execute faster than just `.ToList()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It makes sense if the compiler infers one type and you want to specify another. It doesn't make sense otherwise.

For example, suppose you have an `IEnumerable<string>` and want to create a `List<T>`... if you want a `List<string>` then just call `ToList()`. If you want to use generic covariance and get a `List<object>`, call `ToList<object>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = new [] { "foo" };
List<string> stringList = strings.ToList();
List<object> objectList = strings.ToList<object>();
```

The generated IL for the middle line will be the same whether you use the above code or

```
List<string> stringList = strings.ToList<string>();
```

It's just a matter of the compiler inferring the type for you.

> Will `.ToList<SomeClass>()` execute faster than just `.ToList()`?

No, due to the above... the same code is generated.

Answer (score 7):

It's the same method

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source);
```

The type parameter can be inferred by the compiler, so you don't need to specify it (unless you need a `List` of different type than the `IEnumerable` - in that case you need to specify the type explicitly).